# How can I apply my own style to the uploadify gray-gradient button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, upload, uploadify

I use jQuery UI around my site and am wondering how I can use the style for an upload button rather than the standard gray uploadify button.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").button();
        $("input:button").button();
        $("#file_upload").button();

  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'files/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'files/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'files/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : 'uploads/',
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'buttonText'  : 'Choose Pictures',
    'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
      alert(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded successfully!');
    },
    'hideButton'  : true
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="upload_images" name="form1" action="">
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
</form>
```

Is this possible? I tried using the `buttonimg` option but that didn't seem to have very good results as I couldn't see any text over the "button". As you can see below I also am trying the hidebutton option, but this just hides the gray button. Any ideas?

Comment: You may just have to bite the bullet and just create an image with the text on it; that would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the package Uploadify, it seems like the grey button was implemented using Adobe flash.  If you try checking the button in Firebug, you'll see that it's an embedded flash object.

Sorry, don't think there's any solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the grey button style of Uploadify. I have just added below stuffs:

```
'buttonImg': 'images/create_album.png',
'width': '273',
'height': '51',
'wmode': 'transparent',
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonImg': 'images/create_album.png',
            'width': '273',
            'height': '51',
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'onAllComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {                    
            }
        });

    });
```